# What is the word for obtaining a rhyme by mispronouncing a word using a regional dialect?

Tags: pronunciation, rhymes

Take the lyrics:

> ... Now he lives in the islands
>   Fishing the pilin's   (instead of pilings) ...

Is there a word that means to alter the pronunciation to achieve a rhyme (in song)?

Comment: Actually that's a true rhyme, because most people would say /'paylənz/ instead of /'paylɪŋz/. Perhaps what you want is the term for a rhyme that **only** works in print (like _wind / find_); that's "eye rhyme" (i.e, a rhyme for the eye only, not the ear).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyme#Types_of_rhyme

Comment: @JohnLawler I say the full word, /'paylɪŋz/. I guess I'm not most people?

Comment: @ErikE: So do I, as do many speakers of British English.

Comment: @JohnLawler I have only heard and said /'paylɪŋz/ myself so far. The mispronounciation may be common in a large region/whole country, but the "official" pronunciation does not let "islands" rhyme with "pilings"/"pilin's".

Comment: @JohnLawler, *wind* / *find* appears to have worked when spoken (well, sung) in some periods.

Comment: @JohnLawler: And not only that. I pronounce 'islands' as  /ˈaɪləndz/ much of the time, so even if we allow /'paylənz/ instead of /'paylɪŋz/, there's still no rhyme for many of us.

Comment: Right, the rhyme is given by the singer, so that if you were to read it, it wouldn't look rhymed, but when heard (as sung by Jimmy Buffet in "He went to Paris"), it rhymes in the song, but doesn't on paper.  I'm looking for the word that defines that activity of mis-pronunciation to achieve a rhyme.

Comment: And I see I didn't make clear in my comment that this isn't **mis**-pronunciation -- this is Pronunciation, pure and simple. The spelling of a word or phrase does not determine its pronunciation; spelling is in a different orbit entirely. Pick your accent, follow the rules, and out comes a pronunciation. Some rhyme, some don't, but none are mispronunciations, unless in some particular case the speaker meant to pronounce one thing and pronounced a different one instead.

Comment: Oh, and what makes anyone think there is a special term for that, by the way? How often is it needed?

Comment: Did you get up on the wrong side of the bed this morning @John Lawler?

Comment: I do really wonder why people think there is a magic box in English where one can find a single word to describe even the most obscure and improbable circumstances perfectly. English mostly uses phrases instead of single words for precision; a precise single word is something of a rarity.

Comment: Could it be the large number of counter examples to your theory:  Bake, Run, Eat, Rhyme, Sing, Write, Pronounce, Pontificate, Elaborate, Masticate, Ruminate, Officiate ... we have lots of words that describe actions, some of which are widely used, some not.  Words like Pedantry come to mind as well.  In a language with more than 100,000 words, to wonder if there is one that describes something like this activity is not far fetched.

Answer (score 4):

In rap music, the term **bending words** is used when rappers create rhymes where there otherwise wouldn't be a true rhyme.

Here is a [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7T5bm3Pejg) where the artist Eminem talked with the news program *60 Minutes* on this topic.

There may be other names for this rhyming device, too – I'm not claiming this is *the*
 right answer.  Or, put another way:

> *There may be other terms, too, maybe ones that are fancier*
>   *I'm not saying that this is the only right answer*
>   *But if you don't like it, please don't be cussin'*
>   *I thought it was worth mentioning in our discussion*

Comment: Your use of mismatched rhyme / Unpleasantly warps my mind! / From this unruly, vexing game / Would you kindly refrain?

Answer (score 1):

The term I've heard used for this sort of fudging is "[allowable rhyme](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Rhyming_Dictionary_of_the_English_La.html?id=sX4CAAAAYAAJ)" - meaning that it's allowable by a generous interpretation of the rules, but it just ain't right.

[H.P. Lovecraft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._P._Lovecraft) (he of Gothic-horror fame, [*ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ph%27nglui_mglw%27nafh_Cthulhu_R%27lyeh_wgah%27nagl_fhtagn)!) wrote a famous essay on the topic called, appropriately enough, [The Allowable Rhyme](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/litcrit/ar.asp).  He did not approve.

Comment: My own favorite-ever example of an allowable rhyme is by Tom Lehrer: "You may end up like Oedipus / I'd rather marry a duck-billed platypus / Than end up like old Oedipux Rex!"